# Do I need Setup.hs file when creating Haskell projects?

Tags: cabal, haskell-stack

I use `stack new <name>`, then `hpack-convert` and add dependencies into `package.yaml` in order to skip ceremony and start writing Haskell code.

Why is there's always a `Setup.hs` file? I don't use custom setups as far as I know. Will I need to include this file at some point?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's just an old haskell convention that "Setup.hs" can be used to build the package, even for simple build types.  Pretty sure it can be removed without having issues.