# Will users be diverted from a package if it's not passing `cabal check` for `cabal` `1.22` due to the absence of `Setup.hs`?

Tags: haskell, cabal

`stack new` usually creates a default `Setup.hs` file. I removed it from a project and it still builds alright for any `lts` resolver down to `lts-2`. It also passes `cabal check` at least for `cabal` version `1.24`. (Though not for `cabal` `1.22`.)

Can I conclude from this result that including a default `Setup.hs` in a project is not trendy anymore and I can drop it? In particular, will many prospective users be diverted from installing the package if it's not passing `cabal check` for `cabal` `1.22`?

P.S. This question is more specific than [the other, similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390981) in that I want to know, specifically, if the package not passing `cabal check` for a certain version of `cabal` due to the absence of an otherwise unnecessary `Setup.hs` will be counted against that package in some situations, and whether there are any other downsides to not having a `Setup.hs` in a project, considering the current state of the Haskell ecosystem. Whether a `Setup.hs` is necessary or useful overall is not a question here.

Comment: Indeed I don't see the point of having a `Setup.hs` when it's only the default one anyway (as it is in, like...? probably 99% of all projects).

Answer (score 1):

If you run `cabal sdist` on a project without a `Setup.hs` file, `cabal` creates one for you -- try it!

As such, there's no point to removing the file, because it will just get regenerated when you package for distribution anyway.

Comment: The point is removing clutter. For example, if I have an `hpack`'s `package.yaml` added to version control, I would not add `example.cabal` to version control, but rather to an ignore list, because, when someone builds the package with `stack`, it will be regenerated under the hood. So long as `Setup.hs` can be regenerated, I will be doing the same for it. I will report further as I have it working.